# Mocking ActionContext.getContext().getSession() returns null

Tags: java, junit, struts2, mockito, actioncontext

I am trying to write jUnit test case for following method.

```
public class MyClass {

  public static Map<String, Object> getSession() {
    Map<String, Object> session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
    return session;
  }
}
```

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17724340/how-to-get-an-actioncontext-from-struts-2-during-acceptance-tests) question and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25436615/struts2-junit-actioncontext-objects) question and tried to  mock `ActionContext`. But still session is `null`.

```
    public class TestClass {
        
        private HttpServletRequest request;
        private HttpSession session;
    
        @Before
        public void setUp() {
            // mock the session
            session = mock(HttpSession.class);
            // mock the request
            request = mock(HttpServletRequest);
            when(request.getSession()).thenReturn(session);
    
            // set the context
            Map<String, Object> contextMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            contextMap.put(StrutsStatics.HTTP_REQUEST, request);
            ActionContext.setContext(new ActionContext(contextMap));
        }
    
        @After
        public void destroyTests() {
           ActionContext.setContext(null);
        }

@Test
    public void testGetSession() {        
        Map<String, Object> session =MyClass.getSession();
        //session is null here

    }

}
```

Is there something I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/19649952/1700321.

Comment: Where are you getting `null` session? In `testGetSession()` or `getSession()`

Comment: @alayor on testGetSession()

Comment: I guess you need to show code from `MyClass` then. Can you show the code where this class is returning the session from `ActionContext`?

Comment: @alayor I edited my original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code to the context map, since it's empty context created you should set the session into action context.

```
contextMap.put(ActionContext.SESSION, new SessionMap(request));
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.